# Unscramble words Challenge - improve my bash solution

Tags: bash, perl, string-comparison, scramble

There is a Capture the Flag challenge

I have two files; one with scrambled text like this with about 550 entries

```
dnaoyt
cinuertdso
bda
haey
tolpap
...
```

The second file is a dictionary with about 9,000 entries

```
radar
ccd
gcc
fcc
historical
...
```

The goal is to find the right, unscrambled version of the word, which is contained in the dictionary file.

My approach is to sort the characters from the first word from the first file and then look up if the first word from the second file has the same length. If so then sort that too and compare them.

This is my fully functional bash script, but it is very slow.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
    var=0
    ro=$(echo $p | perl -F -lane 'print sort @F')
    len_ro=${#ro}
    while IFS="" read -r o || [ -n "$o" ]
    do
        ro2=$(echo $o | perl -F -lane 'print sort @ F')
        len_ro2=${#ro2}
        let "var+=1"
        if [ $len_ro == $len_ro2 ]; then
            if  [ $ro == $ro2 ]; then
                echo $o >> new.txt
                echo $var >> whichline.txt
            fi
        fi
    done < dictionary.txt
done < scrambled-words.txt
```

I have also tried converting all characters to ASCII integers and sum each word, but while comparing I realized that the sum of a different char pattern may have the same sum.

[edit]
For the records:
- no anagrams contained in dictionary
- to get the flag, you need to export the unscrambled words as one blob and ans make a SHA-Hash out of it (thats the flag)
- link to ctf for guy who wanted the files https://challenges.reply.com/tamtamy/user/login.action

Comment: It works yes?  The best improvement for speed is to do it in another language like Perl (the whole thing), Python, ...  It will run **MUCH** faster than bash since once interpreted it does not create a bunch of shells to run.  There might be other algorithms that are more efficient, but that language change will have a huge impact.

Comment: Apart from choice of language, for every line of `scrambled-words.txt`, you process the complete `dictionary.txt` file. Your question might be a better match for   [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) - make sure it is [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there, though.

Comment: Two things immediately stand out: (1) Nested loops mean you're re-reading `dictionary.txt` in its entirety for every single word in `scrambled-words.txt`. If you are clever you only need to read the dictionary once. Avoid any nested loops. (2) You're calling `perl` 550×9900 times, which is incredibly inefficient. You should really only need to call it once per file at most. Either write the whole script in perl, or if you stick with bash avoid calling perl so much.

Comment: Also, you'll get false matches for anagrams: your input word "listen" would show up as a match for "silent" because they both sort to "eilnst".

Comment: Can you provide us the two files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off creating a lookup dictionary (keyed by the sorted word) from the dictionary file.

Your loop body is executed 550 * 9,000 = 4,950,000 times (O(N*M)).

The solution I propose executes two loops of at most 9,000 passes each (O(N+M)).

Bonus: It finds all possible solutions at no cost.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my $dict_qfn      = "dictionary.txt";
my $scrambled_qfn = "scrambled-words.txt";

sub key { join "", sort split //, $_[0] }

my %dict;
{
   open(my $fh, "<", $dict_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$dict_qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      push @{ $dict{key($_)} }, $_;
   }
}

{
   open(my $fh, "<", $scrambled_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$scrambled_qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      my $matches = $dict{key($_)};
      say "$_ matches @$matches" if $matches;
   }
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if this only takes one millionths of the time of your solution for the sizes you provided (and it scales so much better than yours if you were to increase the sizes).

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this with gawk

```
gawk '
NR == FNR {
    dict[csort()] = $0
    next
}

{
    print dict[csort()]
}

function csort(    chars, sorted) {
    split($0, chars, "")
    asort(chars)
    for (i in chars)
        sorted = sorted chars[i]

    return sorted
}' dictionary.txt scrambled-words.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's perl-free solution I came up with using `sort` and `join`:

```
sort_letters() {
    # Splits each letter onto a line, sorts the letters, then joins them
    #   e.g. "hello" becomes "ehllo"
    echo "${1}" | fold-b1 | sort | tr -d '\n'
}


# For each input file...
for input in "dict.txt" "words.txt"; do
    # Convert each line to [sorted] [original]
    #  then sort and save the results with a .sorted extension
    while read -r original; do
        sorted=$(sort_letters "${original}")
        echo "${sorted} ${original}"
    done < "${input}" | sort > "${input}.sorted"
done

# Join the two files on the [sorted] word
#   outputting the scrambled and unscrambed words
join -j 1 -o 1.2,2.2 "words.txt.sorted" "dict.txt.sorted"
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried something very alike, but a bit different.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<scrambled-words.txt
while read -r line <&3; do
   printf "%s" ${line} | perl -F -lane 'print sort @F'
done>scrambled-words_sorted.txt
exec 3>&-

exec 3<dictionary.txt
while read -r line <&3; do
   printf "%s" ${line} | perl -F -lane 'print sort @F'
done>dictionary_sorted.txt
exec 3>&-

printf "" > whichline.txt
exec 3<scrambled-words_sorted.txt
while read -r line <&3; do
   counter="$((++counter))"
   grep -n -e "^${line}$" dictionary_sorted.txt | cut -d ':' -f 1 | tr -d '\n' >>whichline.txt   printf "\n" >>whichline.txt
done   
exec 3>&-
```

As you can see I don't create a `new.txt` file; instead I only create `whichline.txt` with a blank line where the word doesn't match. You can easily paste them up to create `new.txt`.

The logic behind the script is nearly the logic behind yours, with the exception that I called `perl` less times and I save two support files.
I think (but I am not sure) that creating them and cycle only one file will be better than ~5kk calls of `perl`. This way "only" ~10k times is called.

Finally, I decided to use `grep` because it's (maybe) the fastest regex matcher, and searching for the entire line the lenght is intrinsic in the regex.

Please, note that what @benjamin-w said is still valid and, in that case, `grep` will reply badly and I did not managed it!

I hope this could help [: